# Find the last two digits of $2015^{2016}-2017$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I proved it by the binomial theorem, $08$.
It is correct but I also tried proving it by modular arithmetic using Fermat's little theorem. I proved till
$2015^{2016} - 2017 = 2017a + 1$

What to do next? Please tell me.

Comment: I suspect that the problem composer's intent is for you to notice that for all $~a,b \in \Bbb{Z^+},~(100a + 25)^b \equiv 25 \pmod{100}.~$  Apparently, you fulfilled the task via the binomial theorem, which means that you have navigated the path that I suspect the problem composer intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let
$$ n = 2015^{2016}-2017 $$
If you reduce everything modulo $100$ you'll get
$$n \equiv 15 ^ {2016} - 17 \,\, \text{(mod 100)}$$

To reduce $15^{2016}$ , we calculate
$$15^2=125\equiv 25 \,\,\text{(mod $100$)}$$ so
$$15^{2016} = 25^{1008}$$
As $25^2 = 625 \equiv 25 \,\,\text{(mod 100)}$, every power of $25$ is equivalent to $25$ (mod 100).

In the end:

$$ \begin{align}
     n &\equiv 15 ^ {2016} - 17 \,\,&\text{(mod 100)} \\
     &\equiv (15^2)^{1008} - 17  \,\,&\text{(mod 100)}\\
     &\equiv 25^{1008} - 17  \,\,&\text{(mod 100)}\\
     &\equiv 25 -17  \,\,&\text{(mod 100)}\\
     &\equiv 8  \,\,&\text{(mod 100)}
\end{align}
$$

So the last two digits are $08$.

Comment: But $15$ and $100$ are not relatively prime so how is [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) applicable? For instance, $(18)^{41}\not\equiv 18^1\pmod{100}$

Comment: And particularly, in your case,  $15^{40}\mod 100$ is not $1$ most certainly.

Comment: I feel so ashamed, you are right. I will delete the answer, thank you for pointing it out !

Comment: I couldn't delete it as it was accepted, so I edited to correct it. I agree Sil's answer is cleaner!

Comment: You need not be ashamed, we all make mistakes. :) (+1) for the update. Very nice observation! $25^n\equiv 25\pmod{100}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with modular arithmetic (without Fermat's little theorem however), we have
$$
2015^{2016}-2017\equiv (-1)^{2016}-1=0 \pmod 4
$$

$$
2015^{2016}-2017=403^{2016}5^{2016}-2017\equiv 0+8= 8 \pmod{25}.
$$
Hence combining the two we must have
$$
2015^{2016}-2017\equiv 8 \pmod {100}.
$$